# What does the method setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768)) does in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, dimension

I have a task and it has this sentence "The automated tests should run in a browser resolution of 1024x768px"

This is how I understand it, by setting the browser size into 1024, 768 resolution.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
```

I don't know if this is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, this how you set up resolution if u run your tests locally.

If u run run your tests remotely(any Cloud Testing service), then its gonna be something like this:

capabilities.setCapability("screenResolution", "1920x1080");

Answer (score 0):

### setSize()

As per the Java Docs [setSize()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#setSize-org.openqa.selenium.Dimension-) sets the size of the current browsing window. This command will change the outer window dimension along with the view port and is defined as:

```
void setSize(Dimension targetSize)

Set the size of the current window. This will change the outer window dimension, not just the view port, synonymous to window.resizeTo() in JS.

Parameters:
    targetSize - The target size.
```

where [Dimension](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Dimension.html) implies a [Point](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Point.html) which is defined as:

```
Dimension(int width, int height)
```

So by the line of code:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
```

You are setting the size of the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) with `width` set as **`1024`** and `height` set as **`768`** for the current web browsing context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing any error "The method setSize(org.openqa.selenium.Dimension) in the type WebDriver.Window is not applicable for the arguments (java.awt.Dimension)"   >>>>>>

Then import this method from package "org.openqa.selenium'.

You might have imported wrong package of "java.awt.Dimension".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).